# Must you call CGContextClosePath after CGContextBeginPath?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics

If my path ends where it starts, then is it OK to omit the call to `CGContextClosePath`?

Comment: Of course, otherwise the path will not be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily, only if you want to close the subpath. According to **iOS Developer Library : Quartz 2D Programming Guide**:

> [Closing a Subpath](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-SW27)
>
> To close the current subpath, your application
> should call CGContextClosePath. This function adds a line segment from
> the current point to the starting point of the subpath and closes the
> subpath. Lines, arcs, and curves that end at the starting point of a
> subpath do not actually close the subpath. *You must explicitly call
> `CGContextClosePath` to close a subpath.*

Comment: It actually doesn't say you must call `CGContextClosePath` after `CGContextBeginPath`. What it says is that in order to close a subpath you need to call `CGContextClosePath`. But if you don't *want* to close your subpath, then presumably you shouldn't call this method.

Comment: @KevinBallard Thanks, I updated the answer. So, why would you want to "close" a subpath that already ends where it starts?

Comment: @MattDiPasquale: It's possible it has some effect on fill behavior, or line join style, or some other quirks of drawing.

Comment: Closing the path ensures that you get a line join at the start/end  point.  The documentation used to mention this prominently, but I can't find that currently.